# How can i remove home directory from download directory without deleting it

Tags: 14.04, root, home-directory, symbolic-link, rm

In my Downloads folder when I make `ls` I see the home directory, and I don't know why, I want to remove it but I am afraid to remove my home folder.
Can anyone tell me how I can just remove the home directory in the Downloads folder and keep it in the root folder?

here you can see a picture of what I get when I make `ls` command in the Downloads directory:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you're seeing is likely a file with name `~`, not your home directory or link to your home directory. Do this: `file ~/Downloads/*` or `find $HOME/Downloads -type f` . You will see it listed as a regular file

Comment: do an ls -la and post that

Comment: yes it is right it is a regular file, so if i remove it, i will keep my original home directory ?

Comment: this is what i get when i make `ls -la`:

`-rw-------  1 root    root         1024 nov 28 20:24 ~`